# Auto align is not straight

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\newcommand{\lt}{\latintext} 
\newcommand{\gt}{\greektext}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document} 

\textit{\Large Ερώτημα 2}\\[0.2in]
\lt
(a)\\

\gt 
\underline{Πίνακας \lt Orderlines}\\[0.2in]
\lt
R\begin{scriptsize}  orderlines\end{scriptsize}=60.350

r = 50 bytes

bfr = $\lfloor (b/r)\rfloor$

\end{document}
```

and my result is:

[image]

Why is Rorderlines not aligned with the rest of the text? Did I change it by mistake?

Comment: Add a blank line after `\lt`

Comment: The paragraph is not ended, and the line with "Rorderlines" is not indented. To terminate the paragraph, issue `\par` or add a blank line.

Comment: Don't use `\lt` and `\gt`; rather use `\textlatin{(a)}` that doesn't need to keep track of the character set.

Comment: It seems that you're using LaTeX like a word processor, which is wrong: too many forced line breaks mean you're misusing the tool. It should be `R_{\mathrm{orderlines}}` (in math mode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this more to your liking?  As I said in my comment, a blank line seems necessary after `\lt`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\newcommand{\lt}{\latintext} 
\newcommand{\gt}{\greektext}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document} 

\textit{\Large Ερώτημα 2}\\[0.2in]
\lt
(a)\\

\gt 
\underline{Πίνακας \lt Orderlines}\lt\\

R\begin{scriptsize}  orderlines\end{scriptsize}=60.350

r = 50 bytes

bfr = $\lfloor (b/r)\rfloor$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes,this works great, but can you please explain me why that happened?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic  Actually, karl's explanation in your question is the proper response.  With the "\\", the paragraph is not ended, and thus the indent disappears.